# Myriad pro bug in ie6

Tags: fonts, internet-explorer-6

i am  using Myriad pro as one of my fonts in my site, but in IE6 for cyrillic part of the text the font is changed from Myriad pro to Times new roman. I want to know if there is to fix this. Any decisions and replies are welcomed

Comment: Why are you still supporting ie6? http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: In my country (Bulgaria) many people still don't have such a tech culture and when Windows XP is installed they don't touch the browser like in banks,posts.

Comment: In that case, you might want to check out Cufon. It's a way to use fonts in older browsers.